# \widehat and \widetilde are too small for certain letters with kpfont-otf

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math, kpfonts

Consider the following example, I think the `\widehat` seems to be too small for single letters. When using `\widehat`, one usually would expect getting a wider hat even for single letters (since for narrow hat there is already a `\hat` for it). Though the real wide hat can be triggered by adding horizontal space, for the letter `C`, if I add `\,` around the letter, the `\widehat` would be then a little bit too large.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}

\begin{document}
\[
    \hat{c} \hat{C} \hat{\mathcal{C}}
\]
\[
    \widehat{c} \widehat{C} \widehat{\mathcal{C}}
\]
\[
    \widehat{c\,} \widehat{C\,} \widehat{\mathcal{C}\,}
\]
\[
    \widehat{\,c\,} \widehat{\,C\,} \widehat{\,\mathcal{C}\,}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The same problem happens with `\widetilde`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}

\begin{document}
\[
    \widehat{C} \widehat{\mathcal{C}} \widehat{U}
\]
\[
    \widetilde{C} \widetilde{\mathcal{C}} \widetilde{U}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, use the suitable bug reporting method.

Comment: @egreg Do you think it is a bug? I thought that it is by design... I shall send an email to Daniel Flipo tomorrow morning then.

Comment: I weirdly get slightly different results with lualatex and xelatex.

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you expect? Do you want it to look as in the third row? The font has in the widehat slot one small base character (width 0) and the next hvariant is the one you see in the third row (width 737).

Comment: @mickep I would expect to get a nice wide hat or tilde without manually adding space (which would cause the hat or tilde to be too large). In my opinion the wide symbol should always shown to be "wide" (as in `\widetilde{U}`) even for single letters, for the consistency (the wide symbol does not always need to be too wide, but it should at least be wider than the normal `\hat` or `tilde`). I think the default CM font looks better from this point of view.

Answer (score 1):

In `unicode-math-table.tex` you can find (a few spaces removed for readability)

```
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"00302}{\hat        }{\mathaccent}{circumflex accent}%
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"00302}{\widehat    }{\mathaccentwide}{circumflex accent}%
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"00303}{\tilde      }{\mathaccent}{tilde}%
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"00303}{\widetilde  }{\mathaccentwide}{tilde}%
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"00304}{\bar        }{\mathaccent}{macron}%
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"00305}{\overbar    }{\mathaccent}{overbar embellishment}%
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"00305}{\wideoverbar}{\mathaccentwide}{stretchy overbar embellishment}%
```

This means that `\hat` and `\widehat` point to the same slot, with the difference that `\widehat` will “measure” the accentee and choose the variant glyph more suited to cover it.

If you load `unicode-math` instead of `kpfonts-otf`, you'll see that in all cases a wider variant is chosen, but `\widehat{I}` or `\widetilde{I}` would chose the same as `\hat` or `\tilde`.

It's just a question of sizes and font parameters. Probably the first wider  variant of U+00302 is too wide in KpFonts. But it's also a good reason not to abuse `\widehat` and `\widetilde`; in *all* the cases you show, `\hat` and `\tilde` are better.

Comment: It's just that in my professor's course note all the prolongement of maps or objects are shown with a wide hat (with the default CM font) which look quite nice and I would like to do the same. However with `kpfonts-otf` I cannot usually get a nice wide hat for single letters -- it would be either too narrow or too wide.

Comment: I disagree. In the above example, `\widetilde{U}` is definitely better than `\tilde{U}`.

Comment: @Jinwen That’s why I recommend to file a report

Comment: I agree with @egreg on two points: a) for me the base \hat and \tilde look fine on single letters; b) it might be useful to add a intermediate  variant between the base character and the current first enlarged variant (both seen on Jinwen example).  I will consider this for the next `kpfonts-otf` release, but expect it too soon.